# парные табы на jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

Всем привет, скажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы этот скрипт работал персонально для каждого wrapper с табами ?

```js
  $(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
  $(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
   $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
   $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
  }).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
  $(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
   $(this).siblings(".tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
   $(this).parent().parent().children(".tab_content").children(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
  }).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Один из вариантов. Суть - указать внутри каких div стоит работать. То есть, идти от родительского.